Understanding the '-a' option of the 'cp' command
From man cp, abridged:


-a: Archive mode. Same as -RpP options. Preserves structure and attributes of files but not directory structure.
-R: If source_file designates a directory, cp copies the directory and the entire subtree connected at that point.  If the source_file ends in a /, the contents of the directory are copied rather than the directory itself.
-p: Cause cp to preserve the following attributes of each source file in the copy: modification time, access time, file flags, file mode, user ID, and group ID, as allowed by permissions.
-P: No symbolic links are followed. This is the default if the -R option is specified.



-P is described as included in -R, but then why -a is described as -RpP rather than just -Rp?
What does it mean -a doesn't preserve directory structure? Already answered on Ask Different, https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/267220
Does both the -R and -P flags make sense when copying files, not folders, e.g., when doing cp *.(txt|md) docs/?

zsh 5.9 (x86_64-apple-darwin23.0), macOS 14.4.1

This (point 2) is answered in the Apple-specific stack: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/267220/what-does-it-mean-for-cp-a-to-not-preserve-directory-structure  Feel free to add an answer based on this, using your own words.

Looks like a nonsensical addition by Apple. FreeBSD's (on which it is based) doesn't have that sentence.

@StéphaneChazelas Which sentence exactly?

The one about directory structure. For -a == -RpP, the implication would be that -L -a would cancel the -L.

About 3, no -R is pointless unless any of those files are of type directory and you want them and their contents copied recursively. Should be cp -- *.(txt|md) docs/ btw (or cp -- *.(txt|md)(.) docs/ to copy only those of type regular or cp -- *.(txt|md)(^/) docs/ to copy those of any type except directory)

@StéphaneChazelas From man cp: "-R: This option also causes symbolic links to be copied, rather than indirected through". Isn't it that using -R for files and not directories still makes sense then?

@jsx97 good point, the fact that -R implies -P with some implementations of cp like  yours would indeed mean that it also has an influence on the copying of symlinks in those.

@StéphaneChazelas Ah, yes, sorry. Of course, it makes no sense to use -R when copying files, because Bash and Zsh already provide -P, exactly for this. Personally, I prefer -a (= -RpP) for folders and -pP for files.

@jsx97 cp has nothing to do with zsh nor bash. It's a separate executable like Firefox, tar or rm (though zsh has a rm builtin in its zsh/files module).


The -P, -H and -L standard options are mutually exclusive. Setting one unsets the other two. The last one (from left to right) wins. -LHP is the same as -P, -HPL is the same as -L. Now when the doc says that the -P behaviour is the default with -R does not imply that -P is applied as well when you use -R. cp -LR is the same as cp -RL and not the same as as cp -R / cp -RP.
On the other hand, -a (not a standard option) is the same as -RpP, cp -L -a is cp -L -RpP and -P cancels -L. You need cp -a -L if you want -L to apply.
You can follow it in the source code FreeBSD's cp (on which macos' is based):
     switch (ch) {
     case 'H':
         Hflag = 1;
         Lflag = Pflag = 0;
         break;
     case 'L':
         Lflag = 1;
         Hflag = Pflag = 0;
         break;
     case 'P':
         Pflag = 1;
         Hflag = Lflag = 0;
         break;

[...]
     case 'R':
         Rflag = 1;
         break;
     case 'a':
         pflag = 1;
         Rflag = 1;
         Pflag = 1;
         Hflag = Lflag = 0;
         break;


What does it mean -a doesn't preserve directory structure? is not clear to me. The verbiage does not appear in FreeBSD's cp man page, so it must have been added by Apple. The suggestion that it means it will not delete existing files and subdirectories when copying into an already existing directory is not convincing to me. You'd probably have to ask Apple (since AFAIK their source code and the revision control history is not publicly available) to know for sure.

Note that it's not files versus directories on Unix. Directory is just one of many types of files. Other types include fifos, sockets, block devices, symlinks, regular files... -R is only intended for the Recursive copying of directories, for other types of files, that has no effect except for one exception which is mostly a side-effect: -R does cause physical traversal as if -P was given, which means that for files of type symlink, whether that's symlinks to directories or any other type of file, it's the symlink alone that is being copied, and not its target. If you do want that effect though, you'd rather use the -P option which is intended for that.


